NextJs Rewrites, second rewrite not working
Im trying to do a simple rewrite. So all /app traffic rewrites to /frontend folder, and all /backend traffic rewrites to /backend folder.
I'm getting error 404 if I'm launching: localhost:3000/app/hello
I'm not however getting error 404 if I'm launching: localhost:3000/backend/hello
Following is what I have tried in next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/backend/:path*',
                destination: '/app/backend/:path*',
            },
            {
                source: '/app/:path*',
                destination: '/app/frontend/:path*',
            },
        ]
    }
};

export default nextConfig;

I have page.tsx files in both frontend and backend:
src\app\frontend\hello\page.tsx
export default function World() {
    return (
        <div>
            body
        </div>
    )
}

src\app\backend\hello\page.tsx
export default function World() {
    return (
        <div>
            body
        </div>
    )
}

So to summarize, the first backend rewrite is working perfectly, while /app is not

This will fix your issue:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            // Your backend rewrite part
            {
                source: '/:path*',
                destination: '/frontend/:path*',
            },
        ]
    }
};

Now try to hit localhost:3000/hello and it will redirect you to the expected path localhost:3000/frontend/hello.

If there is src or app in the root directory, next will ignore it and rewrite function will be applied after checking filesystem.
So basically both of your rewrite destination are not existed.
The reason localhost:3000/backend/hello worked is there is a page.tsx at src\app\backend\hello, so rewrite did not applied.
This should work:
  async rewrites() {
    return [
        // looks like backend doesn't need redirect
        {
            source: '/app/:path*',
            destination: '/frontend/:path*', //remove 'app/'
        },
    ]
  }

Hope this helpful to you.
